# Problem to run Sphinx on Ruby on Rails 2.3.2

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, sphinx, thinking-sphinx

Yesterday I was trying to install Sphinx for full-text search on Windows 7. So, I followed [their website's installation steps](http://www.sphinxsearch.com/docs/current.html#installation).
Once I installed its windows service, I ran the indexer and then the test search against my app database and it worked great.

Then, I wanted to make it work on Ruby on Rails 2.3.2, so I downloaded and installed the [thinking-sphinx plugin](http://github.com/freelancing-god/thinking-sphinx/). I followed [these steps](http://freelancing-gods.com/posts/a_concise_guide_to_using_thinking_sphinx), creating the sphinx.conf file at the config directory of my app, and then I ran the rake thinking-sphinx:indexer and it worked great. After that, when I wanted to start it, as it's explained in that guide, it didn't start...it just keep saying "thinking-sphinx:start", and it didn't either stop or start.

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks,
Brian

Answer (score 0):

Well, it seems that without starting it using rake it works anyway...it's maybe because the Sphinx service is already started, so you don't need to start it also with the rake from ruby.

I've got another doubt now...I'm from Argentina and we use accents to write in some words...for example "acción", which means "action" in english. I tried searching that word without the accent(people don't ussually write accents on searches) and it didn't bring any results, but if I search it with the accent, it will bring results.

How can I fix that?

Thanks,
Brian

Comment: Right, you don't need to start it if it's already running. As for your other question, this is documented on thinking sphinx website: http://freelancing-god.github.com/ts/en/advanced_config.html. Look for the `charset_table` option.